# Submit FORM via Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML page that looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form action="/my-url" method="POST">
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

This page is an ANgularJS app. Inside of it, I then have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
      // how?
    }
  }]);
</script>
```

How do I submit the form from the `submitForm` function? In other words, I am trying to programmatically submit the form. How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you have to give it a `name` attribute, then you can use `$scope.formName.submit()`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    ...
  <button type="submit">submit here</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[see](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) in detail